# How can I make the most efficient Hilbert Curve with Turtle [Python 3]?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-turtle, hilbert-curve

I'm trying to make a Hilbert Curve that takes as little time as possible to complete. Here is the code so far (adapted from [Hilbert curve using turtle graphics and recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53243985/hilbert-curve-using-turtle-graphics-and-recursion))

```
from turtle import *
from win32api import GetSystemMetrics



def hilbert_curve(amt, facing, n, start_at_corner=True) -> None:
    if start_at_corner:
        ht()
        up()
        goto(x=(- (GetSystemMetrics(0) - 30) / 2), y=(- (GetSystemMetrics(1) / 2 - 50)))
        down()

    if n < 1:
        return

    try:    # Only here because I find error messages annoying
        left(facing * 90)
        hilbert_curve(amt, - facing, n - 1, False)
        fd(amt)
        right(facing * 90)
        hilbert_curve(amt, facing, n - 1, False)
        fd(amt)
        hilbert_curve(amt, facing, n - 1, False)
        right(facing * 90)
        fd(amt)
        hilbert_curve(amt, - facing, n - 1, False)
        left(facing * 90)

    except Terminator:
        from sys import exit
        exit()


screen = getscreen()
speed(0)
hilbert_curve(5, 1, 15)
screen.mainloop()
```

The issue with this is that the turtle makes a lot of unnecessary turns - at the start and at all connections - I understand why this happens but I don't know how to fix it.

If there are any other things I can change in above code to make the turtle faster, suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short of rethinking the program's entire approach, here's a quick fix that provides noticeable speed up.  We'll use `tracer()` and `update()` to precisely control the graphics.  We don't want to hide any of the drawing (which is possible with `tracer()`) but rather only draw when there is a line to draw, treating all the turtle's turns as internal logic calculations, displaying only the final heading:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def hilbert_curve(distance, facing, n):
    if n < 1:
        return

    turtle.left(facing * 90)
    hilbert_curve(distance, -facing, n - 1)
    turtle.forward(distance)
    screen.update()

    turtle.right(facing * 90)
    hilbert_curve(distance, facing, n - 1)
    turtle.forward(distance)
    screen.update()

    hilbert_curve(distance, facing, n - 1)
    turtle.right(facing * 90)
    turtle.forward(distance)
    screen.update()

    hilbert_curve(distance, -facing, n - 1)
    turtle.left(facing * 90)

screen = Screen()
screen.tracer(False)

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.penup()
turtle.goto(10 - screen.window_width()/2, 20 - screen.window_height()/2)
turtle.pendown()

hilbert_curve(5, 1, 15)

screen.tracer(True)
screen.mainloop()
```

If, on the other hand, you don't care about watching the drawing and simply want to fill the plane as quickly as possible with a Hilbert curve, then remove the `screen.update()` calls from the above code and change this line:

```
screen.tracer(False)
```

to instead be:

```
screen.tracer(1000)
```

to fill the window with the fractal in a few seconds.